# How to configure a sequence already set up in the database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a primary key. Another column has a sequence set up.

This [MS Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences) describes how to add and use a sequence within the model itself. But if my sequence already exists, how do I configure the model to use the existing sequence?

Also in the article, the code is in the context's `OnModelCreating`. How do I use the sequence when having a mapping class?

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is implemented on database side, you don't have to manage it in code in your model. Whe EF Core is inserting a new instance of your model, the property for the column having the sequence must be null, and the value will be automatically generated on database side.